# client certificate forwarding from haproxy to tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl, haproxy

I've been using httpd to offload my SSL processing and forward http requests to tomcat via AJP. I'm now moving to haproxy instead of httpd and HTTP instead of AJP. I am able to connect to haproxy via https and see an appropriate http request arrive at tomcat. when trying to verify the client certificate my tomcat code cannot retrieve the CN from the certificate. I added the following lines to haproxy.cfg in the hope that it will forward the client certificate information in the http header:

```
http-request set-header X-SSL                       %[ssl_fc]
http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-Verify         %[ssl_c_verify]
http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-SHA1           %{+Q}[ssl_c_sha1]
http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-DN             %{+Q}[ssl_c_s_dn]
http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-CN             %{+Q}[ssl_c_s_dn(cn)]
http-request set-header X-SSL-Issuer                %{+Q}[ssl_c_i_dn]
http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-Not-Before     %{+Q}[ssl_c_notbefore]
http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-Not-After      %{+Q}[ssl_c_notafter]
```

looking at the capture file for the http connection I see the following http header:

```
GET /api/subscriber/count?_=1511258656303 HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.20.192
Accept: */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Referer: https://192.168.20.192/dashboard.jsp
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Cookie: gsScrollPos-1158=0; gsScrollPos-536=0; gsScrollPos-873=2579; gsScrollPos-2263=0; gsScrollPos-472=0; gsScrollPos-468=; JSESSIONID=B433B96FB2616A8447703BFAE541DC2C
X-SSL: 1
X-SSL-Client-Verify: 0
X-SSL-Client-SHA1: 
X-SSL-Client-DN: 
X-SSL-Client-CN: 
X-SSL-Issuer: 
X-SSL-Client-Not-Before: 
X-SSL-Client-Not-After: 
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-For: ::ffff:192.168.12.171
Connection: close
```

as you can see the certificate information is blank.

Am I doing something wrong? is there something else needed to pass the certificate to tomcat?
alternatively can this be made to work using AJP?

here is my full haproxy.cfg:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local4

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    # ssl ciphers and options
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:ECDH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend https
    mode http
    bind :::443 ssl crt /opt/vasona/CA/private/sa_bundle.pem ca-file /opt/vasona/CA/certs/crtServer.crt verify optional


    http-request set-header X-SSL                       %[ssl_fc]
    http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-Verify         %[ssl_c_verify]
    http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-SHA1           %{+Q}[ssl_c_sha1]
    http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-DN             %{+Q}[ssl_c_s_dn]
    http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-CN             %{+Q}[ssl_c_s_dn(cn)]
    http-request set-header X-SSL-Issuer                %{+Q}[ssl_c_i_dn]
    http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-Not-Before     %{+Q}[ssl_c_notbefore]
    http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-Not-After      %{+Q}[ssl_c_notafter]
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    default_backend tomcat-mgmt

backend tomcat-mgmt
    mode http
    option tcp-smart-connect
    server tomcat :8009

backend tomcat-cp-events
    mode http
    option tcp-smart-connect
    server tomcat :23237
```

please let me know if any other info is needed. 
Thanks,
Gidon

Answer (score 1):

turns out I was using the wrong certificate file as ca-file. once using the correct pem file the certificate information passes to the backend correctly.

Comment: I am not getting any relevant information from the logs. The below is my logs

Comment: Apr 24 15:26:57 QB-IPL-1205 haproxy[10265]: Connect from 127.0.0.1:46594 to 127.0.0.1:443 (localhost/HTTP)